# what is netstat –nb and how to use it in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been tald that i need to send the progrem that sent or got the packet (packet in scapy) and that I need to use netstat –nb so i guess netstat –nb does that' but i can't find anywhere how to use it on packet, most of the  code i fount was this:

```
import os
output_command = os.popen("netstat -nb").readlines()
```

but i can't understen, it not chacking one packet.
can someone help me to find how i use "netstat -nb " one a packet for finding the progrem that sent or got the packet? (in python)

Answer (score 0):

I found something on Github hope it helps you. [netstat.py written here](http://gist.github.com/abhi-bit/cafd0edcf107ac2f66b9)

this is how **netstat** works.